# Как создать в языке Пайтон список, в котором парными числами будут числа с непарным индексом из случайно сгенерированного списка?

Tags: python, алгоритм, list

Как создать в языке Пайтон список, в котором четными числами будут числа с нечетным индексом из случайно сгенерированного списка, а нечетными числами будут числа с четным индексом из второго случайно сгенерированного списка? В обоих первых списках 10 чисел. Не могу нигде найти информации

Comment: Приведите пример что ли. Что за парные-непарные такие?

Comment: @CrazyElf, четные и нечетные ))

Comment: Уточните какой список у нас есть в начале. Что если четных чисел меньше чем нечетных или наоборот?

Comment: чётными числами - это числами с чётными индексами?

Answer (score 2):

Если я вас правильно понял то так

```
from random import randint  # функция для создания рандомного целого числа

# создаем списки с рандомными числами от -100 до 100(можно указать любые значения)
lst1 = [randint(-100,100) for b in range(10)]  
lst2 = [randint(-100,100) for a in range(10)]

print(lst1,lst2)
list_ = []

i = 0
while i < 20:  # пока элементов в новом списке не будет двадцать
    if i % 2 == 0:  # если число четное
        list_.append(lst1[0])  # добавляем первый элемент 1 списка
        lst1.pop(0)  # и удаляем его из списка 1
    else:  # если число нечетное
        list_.append(lst2[0])  # добавляем первый элемент 2 списка
        lst2.pop(0)  # и удаляем его из списка 2
    i += 1

print(list_)
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне думается, что решение такое:

```
result = [list1[2*i+1] if i%2==0 else list2[2*i] for i in range(10)]
```